# How to optimize the code that uses BigInteger operations for execution time

Tags: java, algorithm, biginteger, palindrome

The following program takes an input number k and generates a palindrome greater than k. The input number k can be of 1000000 digits.

I implemented the above program in Java with jdk 1.6 using the `java.math.BigInteger` class.

Here is the code:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

class Palindrome
{
    private BigInteger reverse(BigInteger inputNumber)
    {
        BigInteger reversedNumber = new BigInteger("0");        
        while(inputNumber.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) > 0)
        {
            reversedNumber = reversedNumber.multiply(BigInteger.TEN);
            reversedNumber = reversedNumber.abs().add(inputNumber.mod(BigInteger.TEN));
            inputNumber = inputNumber.divide(BigInteger.TEN);
        }
        return reversedNumber;
    }

    public BigInteger nextPalindrome(BigInteger inputNumber)
    {
        BigInteger i = new BigInteger(inputNumber.toString());        
        for(i=i.add(BigInteger.ONE);;i=i.add(BigInteger.ONE))
        {            
            if(i.equals(reverse(i)))
                return i;
        }
    }
}

public class NextPalindrome {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in); 

        Palindrome p = new Palindrome();
        BigInteger inputNumber = input.nextBigInteger(); //To store 1000000 digit number
        System.out.println(p.nextPalindrome(inputNumber));
    }
}
```

The code works for the following inputs:
Input : 808, Output : 818
Input : 1311, Output : 1331
Input : 123456789, Output : 123464321
But when Input : 123456789123456789, Output is not generated

How do I optimize the code for larger inputs?

Comment: To check palindrome, why can't you convert `BigInteger` to `String`, and compare it to reverse of that String? That will take out your `reverse(BigInteger)` method.

Comment: Is this project euler problem BTW? Can you also provide link to the problem?

Comment: @RohitJain It is a problem on SPOJ. The problem name is 'Next Palindrome'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably not use `BigInteger` at all, mostly because there is no arithmetic involved here. Whether a number is palindrome or not can be done by converting the number to string, and comparing the string with reverse.

So, first option is you write a method like this:

```
private static boolean isPalindrome(String number) {
    return new StringBuilder(number).reverse().toString().equals(number);
}
```

And for each `BigInteger` from start, convert that to string, and invoke this method, till you get a palindrome.

But that approach will still be heavy, as you will keep on creating new `BigInteger` object (by keeping on adding `1`). So, the trick is, you convert the given number (as string) by setting characters at end indices, matching the character of corresponding start index.

Let's consider your number `123456789`. The process would be like this:

1. `start = 0`, `end = str.length() - 1`
2. If `end` char is greater than `start` char, set the end char to start char. So, in this case, current startChar is `'1'` and endChar is `'9'`. So, the smallest palindrome larger than this number would have `'1'` as the last character, so we replace `'9'` with `'1'`. The number becomes: *12345678**1***.
   (a). If `end` char is greater then `start` char, and `end == start + 1`, then just set `start` char to `end` char and exit.
3. But here we've decreased the number, by setting last index to a lower value. So, let's increase the `end - 1` index by `1`. Number *12345678**1*** will change to -> *1234567**9**1*.
4. start++, end--. Repeat step 2 and 3, until you find a character at `end` index which is less than that at `start` index.
5. Now, at this stage our number is: `123464321`.
6. So now we've `start > end`. Here the algorithm will stop. You got the result as `123464321`.

But suppose your number was: `126456389`, then at step 5, your number would be: *12**6**456**4**21* (with `start = 2`, and `end = str.length() - 2`)

continue at step 5:

- Once you got a end index (**4**) less than start index (**6**) character, set the end index character to start index character. Here, number becomes: *12**6**456**6**21*. Repeat from step 2.

Once `start > end` condition reaches, you will have your palindrome in the string.

Here's the code for above algorithm:

```
public static String getNextPalindrome(String number) {
    char[] str = number.toCharArray();

    int front = 0;
    int back = str.length - 1;

    while (front < back) {
        if (str[back] > str[front]) {
          if (back == front + 1) {
            str[front] = str[back];
          } else {
            str[back] = str[front];
            str[back - 1] = (char) (str[back - 1] + 1);
          }
        } else if (str[back] < str[front]) {
          str[back] = str[front];
        }
        front++;
        back--;
    }

    return new String(str);
}
```

**Note:** The above algorithm hasn't yet considered the case where number is already a palindrome. I'll leave that to you (that's a minor thing though).

Comment: 126000621 is smaller than 126456389.

Comment: @pbabcdefp Looking into that only. :)

Comment: @pbabcdefp Fixed that thing. Silly mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

Write your own custom algorithm. Don't use `BigInteger` the way you do. The current algorithm you use: 1) is straightforward, trivial, pretty much brute force; 2) uses `BigInteger` where it can go without using it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the problem is to return the *next* palindrome after the input.

Here is a method that works:

Convert the `BigInteger` to a `char[]`. Change the second half of the `char[]` by reflecting the first half. Convert the result to a `BigInteger`. If this `BigInteger` is bigger than the original, return it. Otherwise, convert the first *half* of the `char[]` to a `BigInteger`, add one, convert back to a `char[]`, reflect it, convert back to a `BigInteger`, and return it.

This is the basic algorithm, but there are 2 possible pitfalls. (1) You have to take care to ensure that the algorithm works for both even and odd length strings. (2) You also have to pay special attention to the case where the number begins with lots of 9s (as in this case, the result can have more digits than the original).

Good luck!